# Vectors/Generics in java

Tags: java, generics, vector

I'm trying to create a class so that when I enter a few words, such as a names, the computer will only print out if they have HighRights permission. I'm struggling to access the vector from my ex6 class.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
@SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" ) public class Ex6 {

    public static void main(String[] a)
    {
       int i=Integer.parseInt(a[0]);
       if (i==0) {
           Vector ma = new Vector();
          ma.add(new HighRights("Jimmy"));
          ma.add(new HighRights("Jim"));
          ma.add(new HighRights("Mark"));
          ma.add(new HighRights("John"));
          ma.add(new LowRights("Lisa") );
           System.out.println(new Ex6().CountHighs(ma));
        }
         if (i==1) {
           Vector ma = new Vector();
          ma.add(new HighRights("Jimmy"));
          ma.add("I'm not Jimmy" );
           System.out.println(new Ex6().CountHighs(ma));
        }
        if (i==2)  System.out.println(new Ex6().CountHighs(null));

    }
    public static int CountHighs (Vector m) {
      int count = 0;

        try{
            for(int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++)
            {
                if(m.get(i) instanceof HighRights)
                {
                    count++;
                }

            }
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e){
             System.out.println("Error");
             System.exit(0);
             return 0;

      }
      return count;
    }
}
```

This is the class i want to be able to check if they are in highrights or lowrights.

```
import java.util.*;
 public class Ex8 {

    public void printHighUsers(ArrayList<SecurityRights> a){

    }

     public static void main(String[] args)
{

      Vector ma = new Vector();
      ma.add(new HighRights("Jimmy"));
      ma.add(new HighRights("Jim"));
      ma.add(new HighRights("Mark"));
      ma.add(new LowRights("John"));
      ma.add(new LowRights("Lisa") );

     }
    }
}
```

Just some other relevant information that might help, SecruityRights is the superclass to which HighRights and LowRights both extend. I doubt any of the information in those 3 classes would be helpful so have not posted them here.

This is an example of what i'd like to be able to do just because my explanation at the top might have sucked:

For example, if the ArrayList a contains three SecurityRights objects, the first being a LowRights with 
name "John", the second one a HighRights with name "Mary" and the third one a HighRights with name "Keith" then:
printHighUsers(a) will print on screen: "Mary Keith"

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem you're encountering; Where specifically in the code are you seeing the trouble with accessing the vector?

Comment: In the ex8 code, I want to access the Vector but i'm not sure how

Comment: You don't have to import anything from `java.lang`.

Comment: @Makoto yeah, that was just left over from something i wrote previously

Comment: Do you want to access vector ma from Ex 6 in Ex 8? If yes, then you can't access it as it is a local variable.

Comment: Ah ok, yes now i've put them into one class, would i be able to search the vector and check if say "jimmy" is highrights?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the Vector instances with a generic type like <SecurityRights>, this will also
show a problem when adding a String as you did.

The Ex8 should use a List<? extends SecurityRights> so you can pass any list or even Iterable if you just need to go through the elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Ex8 {

    private Vector ma;
    public Ex8() {
      ma = new Vector<SecurityRights>();
    }
    public Vector getMa(){
      return ma;
    }
    public void printHighUsers(ArrayList<SecurityRights> a){
          //check if vector contains any HighRights users from arraylist a.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
           Ex8 example = new Ex8();
           Vector<SecurityRights> ma = example.getMa();
           ma.add(new HighRights("Jimmy"));
           ma.add(new HighRights("Jim"));
           ma.add(new HighRights("Mark"));
           ma.add(new LowRights("John"));
           ma.add(new LowRights("Lisa") );
           example.printHighUsers(/*your ArrayList*/)
    }
}
```